# Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem holds in any NLS. Is the statement true?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem holds in any NLS.
(Normed Linear Space). Is this statement True?

If it is true how to prove it.

I know how to prove it in $\mathbb R$. I proved it in $\mathbb R$ by using supremum infimum of the set. But in NLS supremum infimum concept do not exist.

Can anyone please help me by giving any hint.

Comment: Are you sure this is true?  [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320619/closed-bounded-but-not-compact-subset-of-a-normed-vector-space) or rather the answers, seem to show the opposite.  Or do you mean for you space to be finite-dimensional?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2293062/489079 please check this link

Comment: This is not true in general normed spaces, unless you specify that the sequence is contained in a compact set.

Comment: Can you please give a counter example?@rldias

Comment: The link you posted refers to a finite-dimensional normed vector space.  Not all vector spaces are finite-dimensional.  The link I posted in an earlier comment has counterexamples.

Comment: Bolzano - Wierstrass holds in a normed linear space iff it is finite dimensional. In other words, every infinite dimensional normed linear space has a closed and bounded set which is not compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the space $l_1$ and the sequence $e_n$ (the $n$th unit vector).
This is bounded but had no convergent subsequence.